# Obtener el primer domingo de mes en jQuery

Tags: jquery, calendar

Me podeis ayudar con un rango de dias que no encuentro la manera de hacer? lo tengo que incluir en un if para desencadenar una serie de funciones.

Para el mes de mayo, necesito obtener un rango de dias con respecto al primer 
domingo de mes. O sea,

1) obtener el día del primer domingo del mes de mayo (para cualquier año)
2) después establecer un rango entre 5 días antes y 2 días después.
Por ejemplo: si el primer domingo de mayo calculado resulta ser el día 3, el rango a obtener sería  desde el 28 de abril al 5 de mayo
Cuando el día es fijo, no hay problema: if((mes==5 && (dia>14 && dia<21))){
pero al tener que referirlo a un día de la semana, no doy con ello
Telita verdad? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo 2 soluciones, una utilizando [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) y la otra utilizando [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date).

No se como querés manejar lo del rango, así que simplemente te muestro como obtener cada uno de los datos que necesitás.

---

**Moment.js:**

```js
var sunday = moment('2019-05-01');

while (sunday.format('d') != 0) {
  sunday.add(1, 'day');
}

var min = sunday.clone().subtract(5, 'day');
var max = sunday.clone().add(2, 'day');

console.log('Domingo: ' + sunday.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
console.log('Min: ' + min.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
console.log('Max: ' + max.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Lo primero es inicializar [`moment()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) especificando el día `01` del año/mes que quieras (en éste caso 1º de mayo del 2019).

Con [`format('d')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) pedimos el *número del día de la semana* de la fecha que especificamos, siendo `0` domingo. Lo que hace el `while` es -de ser necesario- agregarle días a la fecha hasta que sea domingo, de esa forma encontramos el primer domingo del mes.

Por último con [`clone()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) hacemos una copia del objeto que creamos antes para no modificarlo y con [`add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) y [`subtract()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) establecemos el rango.

---

**Date():**

```js
// Simplemente para formatear la salida, no es necesaria
function formatDate(date) {
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate()
}

var sunday = new Date(2019, 4, 1);

while (sunday.getDay() != 0) {
  sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 1);
}

var min = new Date(sunday.getTime());
min.setDate(min.getDate() - 5);

var max = new Date(sunday.getTime());
max.setDate(max.getDate() + 2);

console.log('Domingo: ' + formatDate(sunday));
console.log('Min: ' + formatDate(min));
console.log('Max: ' + formatDate(max));
```

Misma lógica que con `moment.js`, empezamos inicializando [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) especificando la fecha inicial, tené en cuenta que los meses empiezan desde `0`.

Con [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDay) obtenemos el número del día de la semana.

Dentro del `while` sumamos de a un día utilizando [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) y [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDate).

Por último creamos los objetos `min` y `max` a partir del [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getTime) de la fecha que encontramos antes.

Comment: Muy bueno!  Para que me sirva para todos los años inicio Date() así:         sunday = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 4, 1);  Para la ejecución cuando se cumpla la fecha la realizo así:  if(new Date()>min && new Date()<max){alert()};  Lo ves bien azeós? Lo he probado cambiando la fecha de sistema en el año actual y funciona bien, pero js da error si paso a años siguientes i no se como validarlo

Comment: @JosepC no veo ningún problema con lo que estás haciendo. No se porque se puede generar un error al adelantar la fecha. Qué error te genera?

Comment: Al cambiar la fecha del sistema a un año posterior, Firefox al recargar la página no carga js remoto (Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js”.). Chrome jquery.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID. Al final si cierro y abro el navegador funciona (si recargo no) y he podido comprobar que funciona el cálculo.  Tonteria de navegadores supongo. Muchas gracias, todo muy rápido, claro y concreto, me ha sido de gran ayuda, un abrazo.

Comment: Entiendo que es un error por el certificado SSL. Tiene fecha de caducidad y al adelantar tu fecha entra en conflicto, no tiene ninguna relación con el código JS. Me alegro que te haya servido.